# jQuery combobox with IE10, cannot open the combobox when there is too much data

Tags: jquery-ui, combobox, internet-explorer-10, large-data

Context: I encountered a problem using jQuery combobox (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) with large data (3000+ items) and IE10.

Problem: When I'm trying to click on button to open the autocomplete list, browser is busy some moment (which is normal, there is a lot of append(), but at the end, focus is on the textbox and autocomplete is opened briefly, but does not remain opened.

It only happens with IE10+, IE9 is working as well as chrome.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e7CX5/ , it's not the last version of jQuery on this exemple, but I've encountered this bug also with last version (jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3)
Code is exactly the same as jQuery website, I've only provided a large select.

Javascript:

```
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
  _create: function() {
    this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
      .insertAfter( this.element );

    this.element.hide();
    this._createAutocomplete();
    this._createShowAllButton();
  },

  _createAutocomplete: function() {
    var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
      value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

    this.input = $( "<input>" )
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .val( value )
      .attr( "title", "" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
      .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
      })
      .tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
      });

    this._on( this.input, {
      autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
          item: ui.item.option
        });
      },

      autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
    });
  },

  _createShowAllButton: function() {
    var input = this.input,
      wasOpen = false;

    $( "<a>" )
      .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
      .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
      .tooltip()
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .button({
        icons: {
          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
      })
      .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
      .mousedown(function() {
        wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
      })
      .click(function() {
        input.focus();

        // Close if already visible
        if ( wasOpen ) {
          return;
        }

        // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
      });
  },

  _source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
      var text = $( this ).text();
      if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
        return {
          label: text,
          value: text,
          option: this
        };
    }) );
  },

  _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

    // Selected an item, nothing to do
    if ( ui.item ) {
      return;
    }

    // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
    var value = this.input.val(),
      valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
      valid = false;
    this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
      if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
        this.selected = valid = true;
        return false;
      }
    });

    // Found a match, nothing to do
    if ( valid ) {
      return;
    }

    // Remove invalid value
    this.input
      .val( "" )
      .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
      .tooltip( "open" );
    this.element.val( "" );
    this._delay(function() {
      this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
    }, 2500 );
    this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
  },

  _destroy: function() {
    this.wrapper.remove();
    this.element.show();
  }
});
})( jQuery );

$(function() {
$( "#combobox" ).combobox();
$( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
  $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
});
 $('#count').html($( "#combobox" ).find('option').length);
});
```

CSS:

```
 .custom-combobox {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  /* support: IE7 */
  *height: 1.7em;
  *top: 0.1em;
}
.custom-combobox-input {
   margin: 0;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="count"></span>
<select id="combobox" style="">
<option value="0">Tous</option><option value="10837">Aucun libellé (ID: 10837)</option>
 3000x
</select>
```

The probleme seems to be caused by blur() event on input set by jQuery autocomplete, but I did not understand why it's working when there is less data.

Thanks in advance for you help !